# How to create SEO-friendly paging for a grid?

Tags: seo, paging, data-paging

I've got this grid (a list of products in an internet shop) for which I've no idea how big it can get. But I suppose a couple hundred items is quite realistic, especially for search results. Maybe even thousands, if we get a big client. :)

Naturally, I should use paging for such a grid. But how to do it so that search engine bots can crawl all the items too? I very much like [this idea](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/789/pagination-best-practice/793#793), but that only has first/last/prev/next links. If a search engine bot has to follow links 200 levels deep to get to the last page, I think it might give up pretty soon, and not enumerate all items.

What is the common(best?) practice for this?

Answer (score 2):

Is it really the grid you want to have index by the search engine or are you afer a product detail page? If the last one is what you want, you can have a dynamic sitemap (XML) and the search engines will take it from there.

Comment: Hmm... true, the product detail pages might be more interesting. That however brings up another question - there might be a lot of products (one of our clients in another project has over 150,000 products in their DB); would a search engine not frown upon an XML file that big?

Answer (score 0):

I run a number of price comparison sites and as such i've had the same issue as you before.  I dont really have a concrete answer, i doubt anyone will have one tbh.

The trick is to try and make each page as unique as possible.  The more unique pages, the better.  Think of it as each page in google is a lottery ticket, the more tickets the more chances you have of winning.

So, back to your question.  We tend to display 20 products per page and then have pagination at the bottom.  AFAIK google and other bots will crawl all links on your site. They wouldnt give up.  What we have noticed though is if your subsequent pages have the same SEO titles, H tags and is basically the same page but with different result sets then Google will NOT add the pages to the index.

Likewise i've looked at the site you suggested and would suggest changing the layout to be text and not images, an example of what i mean is on this site: http://www.shopexplorer.com/lcd-tv/index.html

Another point to remember is the more images etc... on the page the longer the page will take to load the worse your UI will be.  I've also heard it affects quality on SEO ranking algorithms.

Not sure if i've given you enough to go on, but to recap:

1. i would limit the results to 20-30
2. I would use pagination but i would use text and not images
3. i would make sure the paginated pages have distinct enough 'SEO markers' [ title, h1 etc.. ] to be a unique page.
   i.e.
   LCD TV results page 2 > is bad
   LCD TV results from Sony to Samsung > Better

Hopefully i've helped a little

EDIT:

Vlix, i've also seen your question ref: sitemaps.  If you're concerned with that, i wouldnt be, then split the feed into multiple seperate feeds.  Maybe on a category level, brand level etc... I'm not sure but i think google would want as many pages as possible.  It will ignore the ones it doesnt like and just add the unique ones.

That at least, is how i understand it.

Answer (score 0):

SEO is a dark art - nobody will be able to tell you exactly what to do and how to do it. However, I do have some general pointers.

Pleun is right - your objective should be to get the robots to your product detail page - that's likely to be the most keyword-rich, so optimize this page as much as you can! Semantic HTML, don't use images to show text, the usual.

Construct meaningful navigation schemes to lead the robots (and your visitors!) to your product detail pages. So, if you have 150K products, let's hope they are grouped into some kind of hierarchy, and that each (sub)category in that hierarchy has a managable (<50 or so) number of products. If your users have to go through lots and lots of pages in a single category to find the product they're interested in, they're likely to get bored and leave. Make this categorization into a navigation scheme, and make it SEO friendly - e.g. by using friendly URLs.

Create a sitemap - robots will crawl the entire sitemap, though they may not decide to pay much attention to pages that are hard to reach through "normal" navigation, even if they are in the sitemap.xml.

Most robots don't parse more than the first 50-100K of HTML. If your navigation scheme (with a data grid) is too big, the robot won't necessarily pick up or follow links at the end.

Hope this helps!